# Build on device from Xcode versus downloaded from TestFlight - Issues

Tags: ios, xcode, avcapturesession, testflight

I have an issue when running my project on my device, but **only** if it has been downloaded from testFlight. It works fine when I build directly from Xcode to device.

**Potentially relevant details -** 
Using `AVCaptureSession`, my app records segments of video where it can switch between front/rear camera etc. I have handled orientation of each video so when playing back or merging with multiple videos they all play the correct way round.

The playback orientation works as expected on my devices when I've built directly from Xcode. Though from the app dowloaded from Testflight, the orientation of the videos are wrong way round.

Devices used iPhone 5S - 8.1 & iPad 2 7.1

As mentioned, this is **only** an issue from TestFlight builds. I've not posted any code as logic works fine from Xcode. I have used TestFlight a lot over the past year and not come across an issue like this before. It only seems isolated to this video playback.

If anyone has had similar issues and knows how to resolve or has suggestion, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered why my testFlight build was acting different from my Xcode build and it all came down to Build Configuration settings within Xcode

I edited scheme which which brought up build options and within the Run option I changed Build Configuration from Debug to Release.

[image]

Although this never solved the video issue, it did allow the app to act as it would on release. I will now be able to continue test of my issue, but thought other people experiencing differences in their Xcode and test builds may wish to know about this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to be using Swift. Apple changed their certs  and added an extra field as part of the process. Existing certs do not work when including external libraries that include Swift code. I lost a good chunk of time to this. Here is the explanation form TestFlight competitor AirSign.

https://www.airsignapp.com/ios-apps-using-swift-crash-when-signed-with-inhouse-certificate/

If this is the case, the conclusion is generate a new cert and a new provisioning profile using the cert. You may have to revoke your old cert if you have too many.

If you build directly from your machine you are using your development Cert. If you go through TestFlight you are using you distribution cert. What happens if you take the distribution ipa that you are about to upload to TestFlight and try to install that directly onto you device. IF you can not install the app then there is an issue with your distribution cert. I also assume you tried building a new hello world type app and going through TestFlight and then adding AVCaptureSession in a new build of the app and trying that.

To make my life easier I use iFunBox to directly install test ipas directly on my machine bypassing iTunes. Great free app. Just launch, Choose Install on Device and choose the ipa

http://www.i-funbox.com/ifunboxmac/

Comment: Thanks David, I'm using objective-c, though I'll revoke and re-generate certs and try it again. I'm also currently readying about ARM architectures as wondering if it's actually the archived build that's different (as opposed to TestFlight issue itself). Let you know you